# Macro To Copy And Paste From One Workbook To current workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I tried below macro to copy the value in excel name "3" to current excel name "1"  but when i execute  i get the compile error method or data member not found i am not good in Vb script any one please  help me out

```
Sub Update()

Dim sPath As String
Dim objExcel As Application
Dim sValue As String
Dim wbTarget As Workbooks
Dim strName As String
Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
strName = ActiveSheet.Name
sPath = "C:\Users\nikhil.surendran\Desktop\1"
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\nikhil.surendran\Desktop\3" & strName & ".xlsx")

sValue = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With objExcel
.Visible = False
.DisplayAlerts = 0
.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B11").Value = sValue
.ActiveWorkbook.Save
.Quit
End With

End Sub



Thanks in Advance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code : Assuming your code is running from current workbook. You can refer to Current Workbook as `ThisWorkbook` and the workbook which you are opening as `wbTarget`

```
Sub Update()

Dim sPath As String
Dim sValue As String
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim strName As String

strName = ActiveSheet.Name ' Explicitly provide the sheet name
sPath = "C:\Users\nikhil.surendran\Desktop\1"
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\nikhil.surendran\Desktop\3" & strName & ".xlsx")
sValue = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B11").Value = sValue 
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that "3.xlsx" is your file name from which you want to copy the data into the current workbook.And also from first sheet of "3.xlsx" to first sheet of current workbook.

```
  Sub Update()

    Dim wbkSource           As Workbook

    Set wbkSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\nikhil.surendran\Desktop\3.xlsx")
    wbkSource.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

  End Sub
```

Comment: Any reason to use CurrentRegion ?

Comment: just to copy all non continuous data in the sheeet as in post data description was not given....if data is non continuous then usedrange can be used.I didn't use UsedRange as there are some disadvantages of using it.